# Python2.7 wants maximum to be a number but it's taking alphabets like 'hyhhh' as maximum even if 68689798978 is input

Tags: python-2.7

```
largest = None
smallest = None


while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done": break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"

    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    print largest
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    print smallest



print "Minimum" , smallest
print "Maximum", largest
```

Comment: Why don't you debug it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't handle the exception correctly.
You print "Invalid input" if `num = int(num)` fails and just keep going. So in that case `num`just keeps being `num`.

My suggestion would be something like this:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True: 
   num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
   if num == "done": 
      break 
   try: 
      num = int(num) 
   except: 
      print "Invalid input"
      continue # or however you want to handle this case

    if num > largest:
       largest = num
       print largest
    if smallest is None:
       smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
       smallest = num
       print smallest
    print "Minimum" , smallest 
    print "Maximum", largest
```

**OR**

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True: 
   num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
   if num == "done": 
      break 
   try: 
      num = int(num) 
   except: 
      print "Invalid input"
   else:
       if num > largest:
          largest = num
          print largest
       if smallest is None:
          smallest = num
       elif num < smallest:
          smallest = num
          print smallest
    print "Minimum" , smallest 
    print "Maximum", largest
```